# How to display an acf field from a user profile?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I currently have an advanced custom field setup in the user's profile with a field name of `author_title`. This would display what the user does at the company blog.

[image: acf user field]

I currently have the following working but the title only updates for first user and all users get that title instead of being able to use their own.

**Updated**

```
<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); ?>  
<h3><?php the_field('author_title', 'user_' . $current_user->ID); ?></h3>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to get user ID in another way.

Now you get ID for currently logged in user so it shows the same field everywhere. I assume you need show that filed for author posts so:

```
$author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
$author_field = get_field('author_title', 'user_'. $author_id );
```

Comment: When I use the following I get back nothing, Am I missing something else?

Comment: You used that, right? `<?php $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID'); ?>  
<h3><?php the_field('author_title', 'user_'. $author_id ); ?></h3>`