# How to display ACF field Content from User Profile

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I know this is duplicated to this one
[How to display an acf field from a user profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253265/how-to-display-an-acf-field-from-a-user-profile)

I copied the code but it is not working, I tried googling and tried also the code here

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/ and it is not also working

Screenshot:
[image]

screenshot:
[image]

screenshot:
[image]

This is my code:

```
<?php   
    acf_form_head();
    get_header();       
    $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
    $author_field = get_field('author_content', 'user_'. $author_id );
?>

<?php echo $author_field; ?>
```

User Kristen
- should display 'Kristen Content'

User Admin
- should display 'Admin Content'

User Testa
- should display 'Testa Content'

It is just displaying the Admin Content when i tried to logged in user kristen and user testa it should display their own content. I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Do you want to show on user profile page?

Comment: just to display the content of each specific users

Comment: Because I tried to do same as you. If  you give User Role is equal to All, the custom filed will appear in user profile. See the screenshot -> http://prntscr.com/lxc01z 
Do you want to show the user name on post or pages in WP admin panel or show on frontend?

Comment: show on front end

Comment: updated my post @SuYatanar, put screenshots

Comment: Yeah I saw @vince. So, you want to show "Username" + "Content" inside the content area, when the user edit page. Is it correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185538/discussion-between-vince-and-su-yatanar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it

```
<?php $user_data = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id());    
echo $user_data['author_content'][0]; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with this before and here's the solution:

Change

```
$author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
$author_field = get_field('author_content', 'user_'. $author_id );
```

To

```
$author_id = get_current_user_id();
$author_field = get_field('author_content','user_'. $author_id);
```

This will solve it.